# How to create sequence number based on a condition of another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sequence, alter-table

I am trying to add a column in a table but i'm stuck trying to figure out a way to assign sequence number to this column.

- Column `ID` and `C_Seq_No` are from one table (A)
- `D_Seq_No` and `Type` are from another table (B).

I'm trying to join the 2 tables together where anytime `C_Seq_No` shows up with the number "1" three times for one ID, then `D_Seq_No would` create a sequence number of `1, 2, and 3` for that ID.

Here is what I have when I run the query to join the 2 table since I haven't assigned anything to the D_Seq_No column yet:

```
      TABLE A                          TABLE B
ID           C_Seq_No    |    D_Seq_No         Type
123              1       |      NULL            02
123              1       |      NULL            04
123              1       |      NULL            06
123              2       |      NULL            03
123              2       |      NULL            05
123              2       |      NULL            07
```

This is what I want in my query resultset to look like when joining those 2 tables:

```
ID           C_Seq_No        D_Seq_No         Type
123              1             1               02
123              1             2               04
123              1             3               06
123              2             1               03
123              2             2               05
123              2             3               07
```

Comment: What query is creating that result? Because if you have two tables, there isnt any join to generate that.

Comment: Update Table B Set D_Seq_No

Comment: That query doesnt join table A and B

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for row_number.  The call would look like this:

```
select . . .,
       row_number() over (partition by id, c_seq_no order by type) as d_seq_no,
       type
from . . .
```

Comment: Could that be done if id and c_seq_no are from another table? we can't use join statement right?

Comment: @EkansDasnakE . . . There is no requirement that the columns come from the same table.